# Unable to post the data using GPRS

Tags: gsm, at-command, gprs, sim800

I am trying to send the data using GPRS sim800a but I am getting network error , before executing the `AT+SAPBR=1,1`.Signal strength will be good but as soon as `AT+SAPBR=1,1` is executed, led starts blinking continuously and returns response code 601.I am using putty terminal.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue? Here is the AT commands used and the responses I got

```
AT
OK
AT+CGATT=1
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","airtelgprs.com"
OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1
OK
AT+HTTPINIT
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","IP/path:PORT"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","'X-M2M-Origin': "S006"\\r\\n 'Content-Type':'application/json;ty=4'\\r\\n 'Cache-Control':'no-cache'\\r\\n 'Accept':'application/json'"
OK
AT+HTTPDATA=30,80000
DOWNLOAD
{
"m2m:cin":{
"con":"FIRE"}
}
ok
AT+HTTPACTION=1
ok
+HTTPACTION:1,601,0
```

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue? In this case I don't understand the sentence *I am getting network error before executing the AT+SAPBR=1,1*. What error? In the AT log you provided there's no error before +SAPR.

Comment: @Cubo78 yeah i am still facing this issue.If GPRS is connected to network it will blink 1 time per 3 sec right..? after executing AT+SAPBR=1,1 LED will starts blinking continously and at the end AT+HTTPACTION=1 returns  status code 601 instead of 201.

Comment: Is APN correct? Is your traffic plan active?

Comment: @Cubo78 yeah,If i execute AT+CGDCONT? i will get response as +CGDCONT:1,"IP","airtelgprs.com","",0,0...thats the APN right?

Comment: That's not a decisive info: `+CGDCONT` does not do any check about APN Name validity (and even less about its matching with the current SIM). So, if for example you set `AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","JyouthiS"` you will get OK. You need to check with your network provider what's the correct APN. You could also try it with your personal phone in order to test actual APN validity.

Comment: @Cubo78 I checked in my phone..same APN is given in the Phone as well.. i,e airtelgprs.com

Comment: And in the phone you are able to browse?

Comment: @Cubo78 yeah..The issue is i need to setup TLS connection inorder to do that i need to import SSL certificate into GPRS?Does SIM 800A has SSL certificate in it?